# Copy data from excel to existing powerpoint chart

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I need to copy my data in excel to existing powerpoint chart. Here are the part of codes

```
With PP_App.ActivePresentation.Slides(20 + i - 1).Shapes("Chart_Comparison").Chart.ChartData
                    .Activate
                    .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2 + Attributes - 1, 1)).Value = Source5.Range(Cells(7, 3), Cells(7 + Attributes - 1, 3)).Value2
End With
```

But it show error "**Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet; failed**"

But it works when I convert he **numbers** cells using cell address

```
With PP_App.ActivePresentation.Slides(20 + i - 1).Shapes("Chart_Comparison").Chart.ChartData
                .Activate
                .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A8").Value = Source5.Range("C7:C13").Value2
End With
```

The things is, I need to run this automation with loop and with dynamics "Attributes". How to tackle this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You need to fully qualify each `Cells` property, so for example: `Source5.Cells(7, 3)`. Easier solution: use `Resize` method of `Range` class: `Source5.Range("C7").Resize(Attributes - 1)`

Comment: yep  I think you are right. I didn't think of it. I am upvoting this.

Comment: Hi @BrakNicku thank you for your input. I tried .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Resize(Attributes + 1, 0).Value2 = Source5.Range("C7").Resize(Attributes + 7 - 1, 0).Value2. But it shows "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: It should be `Resize(Attributes)` both to match your original code.

Comment: @BrakNicku its worked ! thank you so much, I just need to figure out the logic to match my case.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a better solution, but you can use the two functions below to construct your address in a form that does not give you an error.

```
Function Number2Letter(ColumnNumber As Long) As String
'PURPOSE: Convert a given number into it's corresponding Letter Reference
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault
Dim ColumnLetter As String
'Input Column Number
'Convert To Column Letter
ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
Number2Letter = ColumnLetter
End Function   

Function Letter2Number(ColumnLetter1 As String) As Long
'PURPOSE: Convert a given letter into it's corresponding Numeric Reference
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault
Dim ColumnNumber As Long
'Input Column Letter
'Convert To Column Number
ColumnNumber = Range(ColumnLetter1 & 1).Column
Letter2Number = ColumnNumber
'Display Result
'MsgBox "Column " & ColumnLetter & " = Column " & ColumnNumber   
End Function
```